# return all the text before the first comma

Tags: python, regex

I want to use Regular Expressions to return all the text before the first comma and all the text after that first comma.

I want to have the following:

```
KB= (j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t)
Truth = j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T
```

This is what I have so far:

```
line ='(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t),j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T'
KB = re.findall(r',\((.*?)\)',line)
Truth = re.findall(r',[\w=w]+', line)
```

Comment: This doesn't require rocket science `(.*?),(.*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups to capture the string which was present just before to the first comma and the string after to the first comma.

```
>>> import re
>>> line ='(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t),j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T'
>>> re.findall(r'^([^,]*),(.*)$', line)
[('(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t)', 'j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T')]
>>> KB = re.findall(r'^[^,]*', line)[0]
>>> Truth = re.findall(r'^[^,]*,(.*)', line)[0]
>>> print KB
(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t)
>>> print Truth
j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T
```

You could use `re.search` function also,

```
>>> line ='(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t),j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T'
>>> KB = re.search(r'^([^,]*),(.*)$', line).group(1)
>>> Truth = re.search(r'^([^,]*),(.*)$', line).group(2)
>>> print KB
(j V t) ^ (p V q) ^ (~p V t)
>>> print Truth
j=T,t=F,p=F,q=T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this regex

```
([^,]+)?,(.*)
```